# Why politicians choose Mega Projects in developing countries?

Tags: political-economy

kindly forgive me if this doesn't belong here. I just thought probably it's suited here.

Why do politicians choose mega projects in developing countries instead of spending more on health and education?

Also, are there any noted academics who work in this area.

Kindly enlighten.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the political economy literature on government expenditures. That is a massive literature. A starting point [may be given here](http://dev.wcfia.harvard.edu/sites/default/files/902__jr_WhiteElephants.pdf).

A summary of all possible reasons for so-called white elephants is difficult without a more specific question. Are you interested in corruption, asymmetric information, institutional explanations, political preferences...?

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I don't know much about it, honestly, so I am not sure. 

I am just looking for most valid reasons. What keywords do I search? Any famous researchers working on this that you know of? Much thanks for all help.